# How To Change textbox textmode using checkbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How to change textbox textmode to password if the checkbox is unchecked, then textbox textmode = text if unchecked, then set textmode = password
using javascript?

I tried this code

```
 function test() {
     if ($('#TBPASS12').get(0).type = 'text') {
         document.getElementById('<%= TBPASS12.ClientID %>').type = 'password';
     }
     else if ($('#TBPASS12').get(0).type = 'password') {
         document.getElementById('<%= TBPASS12.ClientID %>').type = 'text';
     }        
 }
```

Comment: Do share parsed/browser rendered HTML ...

Comment: Text mode is read only in javascript. You cannot change the type .

Comment: Assuming this is for something like a "Show Password" feature, I'd recommend two different fields, and show/hide based on the checkbox state. You'll need to figure out the best way to bind the value to both fields, or update one when the other is changed. The field that should actually POST to the server should be the password field, to ensure the payload is semantically proper.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Take the tour! (http://stackoverflow.com/tour)  Gain rep by answering questions, receiving votes on q & a and accepting answers http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

Text mode is `read only` in javascript . So you cannot change the type in js.
You can do only one thing is that, create textbox dynamically and `setattribute` to them and replace with previous

Try like this,

```js
$(function(){
  var inp = document.getElementById("in");
  if(inp.type == 'text'){  
    var newIn = document.createElement('input'); 
    newIn.setAttribute('type', 'password');
    newIn.setAttribute('id', inp.getAttribute('id'));
    newIn.setAttribute('name', inp.getAttribute('name'));
    inp.parentNode.replaceChild(newIn, inp);
    newIn.focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js" data-semver="3.0.0" data-require="jquery"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body> 
   <input id="in" type="text"/>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to reveal a password? As others have said, the textmode is readonly, but you could do a little something.

(EDIT: There used to be a minor bug in the snippet but i fixed it to mirror the bug-less fiddle! The snippet works successfully)

Hope this helps

```js
var x= document.createElement("INPUT");
var y= document.createElement("INPUT");
x.setAttribute("type", "password");
x.id = "<%= TBPASS12.ClientID %>";
x.className = "password1";
x.value ="";
document.body.appendChild(x);

var passwords = document.getElementsByClassName("password1");
for (var i = 0; i < passwords.length; i++) {
   passwords[i].addEventListener('keydown', checkEnter, false);
}

function checkEnter (e){
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    if ((".password1").value !== null) {
      y.setAttribute("type", "text");
      y.id = "value";
      y.value = x.value;
      y.style.display="block";
      document.body.appendChild(y);
     
    }
  }
}
```

```css
input[type="password"] {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
}

input[type="text"] {
  display:none;
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
</body>
```